# Line Following Acute and Right angles and Proportional steering help

Tags: line-following

[image]

I am trying to figure out the logic for a line follower with the path shown in the attached image. I am having trouble with <= 90 degree angle turns. So far, I have been using the logic where if the middle and a side's sensor are on the line and the other sensor is on white, then I turn 90 degrees after driving forwards a little. This does not work for the part marked in blue since the distance designated by the arrows is too small to drive forward any amount and the acute angle causes my car to keep going side to side perpetually half the time I run the program.

Also, if I am using proportional line following in order to approach intersections more perpendicularly, do I have to keep track of which side of the line I am on?

Suggestions on how to improve my design would be appreciated

Comment: Is there a specific reason not to mention the keyword “finite state machine” but paraphrase it with “logic”? This makes it harder to identify existing literature and guide the robot through the maze.

Comment: Could we have a schema were we could see where your robot sensors and actuators are placed?

Comment: In your question the information given are too few. You don't mention what kind of robot you have, for example if your robot is a two wheel drive you are able to turn in place and your problem (i think) is solved.